# What happens when I Double Coins

Tags: speed-warp

I have obtained over 50,000 coins and now have an option to "Double Coins".  What does this do?

[image: Double Coins Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doubles the amount of coins you currently have. One time only, and it applies to the amount of coins you have after deducting the 50,000 coin price. It can be fancy for a jump but obviously it's best saved until you've got a massive fortunate wealth of riches to double it.

Comment: Does it only come once or will I get to do it again sometime?

Comment: Only happens once.